# iOS comparing tintcolor doesn't work

Tags: ios, tintcolor

Here is a quick example I need some help with. I set the text color to green, then I do a check and see if it is green then do some action. It doesn't work, any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

```
[Button1 setTitleColor:[UIColor greenColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

if ([Button1.tintColor isEqual: [UIColor greenColor]])
{
ResultTextLabel.text = @"I detected Button1 tint color is GREEN!";
}
```

It seems so simple yet I've been pulling my hair out for over 3 hrs trying to figure out why this isn't working :(

All help greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: check `button.titlelabel.textcolor` not `Button1.tintColor`

Comment: Oh wow, thank you, works :) :) (I feel dumb now!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this ..

```
if ([Button1.titlelabel.textcolor isEqual: [UIColor greenColor]])
{
    ResultTextLabel.text = @"I detected Button1 tint color is GREEN!";
}
```

It's work fine ..

Answer (score 0):

```
if ([[Button1 titleColorForState:UIControlStateNormal] isEqual:[UIColor greenColor]])
```

hope it helps